# SSIS deadlock because of the need for parallel updates inside the same data flow task

Tags: t-sql, ssis, locking, isolation-level, database-deadlocks

I am creating a data flow task which will be extracting data from a source table and will be updating a destination table as follows:

- 1) Use the **unique id** in the source record to find the record you want to update in the destination table.
- 2) If the ID does not exist in the destination table, check whether the **email** of the source record exists in the destination table instead.

  - a) If the email exists, update the destination record through the **email**. Also update the **unique id** of that destination record.
  - b) If the email does not exist, insert a new record to the destination table.

So, with simple words, I am creating a task that will be updating a table on its **unique id** and if it does not have a match, it will be attempting to update on its **email**. If it still does not find a match, it will be inserting a new record.

This means that I will have two updates running in parallel as you can see in the image (the two circled components will be running in parallel) 
[SSIS_Data_Flow_Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H02Y4.jpg)

Now, this generates a deadlock issue because of those two updates.

I have tried using With (NOLOCK) but this hint is for reading data, not updating it. I also have searched for delay tasks to delay one of the two data pipelines until the other is finished.

Any ideas? Could I maybe design my data flow task differently in order to avoid having multiple parallel updates in the first place?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **NEVER** use `NOLOCK` on a table `UPDATE` (or any other DML statement). That can (**will**) cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: It does not make a difference in my example anyway. Plus, the two updates would not overlap in any records (that was taken care of earlier in the data flow task). Still, deadlock is not advisable and it's understandable. Any other solutions?

Comment: You need to implement an incremental load design pattern. Take a look and Andy Leonard's excellent tutorial. You'll need an extra Lookup, since you'll first want to Lookup and Conditionally Split based on the unique id, then again based on email for the non-matches from the first Split.

Answer (score 0):

with these type of flows i always work with a work table (dest table id, work type (U or I), ...). in a first step i fill a table with work that needs to be done, then i apply the work.

Comment: But wouldn't that result to the same problem? Instead of doing parallel updates to the destination table, you are doing parallel updates to the work table, right?